# Shortest way to count the checked attributes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, aem

I have a list of checkbox in AEM When we hit the checkbox the checked attribute will be placed on the parent element, not in the input box. I want the count how many are checked

```js
console.log(
  $('.isCorrectanswer').attr('checked').length
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxone" />
  <label>checkbox</label>
</coral-checkbox>
<coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxtwo" />
  <label>checkbox</label>
</coral-checkbox>
<coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer">
  <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxthree" />
  <label>checkbox</label>
</coral-checkbox>
<coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer">
  <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxfour" />
  <label>checkbox</label>
</coral-checkbox>
<coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer">
  <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxfive" />
  <label>checkbox</label>
</coral-checkbox>
```

This is not working for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.isCorrectanswer[checked]` selector:

```js
console.log(
  $('.isCorrectanswer[checked]').length
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxone" />
    <label>checkbox</label>
  </coral-checkbox>
  <coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxtwo" />
    <label>checkbox</label>
  </coral-checkbox>
  <coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxthree" />
    <label>checkbox</label>
  </coral-checkbox>
  <coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxfour" />
    <label>checkbox</label>
  </coral-checkbox>
  <coral-checkbox class="isCorrectanswer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="./checkboxfive" />
    <label>checkbox</label>
  </coral-checkbox>
```

(Side note: for the sake of naming consistency, you might consider renaming the class to `isCorrectAnswer`, or `is-correct-answer`, that looks like an easy source of typo bugs as is)